# Convert Graph to Graphics

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

In Mathematica 9, a graph is returned as an object with head `Graph`:

```
In[1]:= CompleteGraph[8] // Head
Out[1]= Graph
```

Right-clicking on a `Graph` object brings a menu with the option "Convert to Graphics". Selecting this option returns a new object which has head `Graphics`. I need to do this programmatically, but I haven't found any command that, applied to `CompleteGraph[8]` (to put an example), returns an object with head `Graphics`, with a plot of the graph.

Is there a command in Mathematica to convert a `Graph` to a `Graphics`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, just after I had posted the question, I found a very simple way to do it:

```
In[1]:= Show[CompleteGraph[8]] // Head
Out[1]= Graphics
```

Answer (score 14):

Contextual menu bindings are defined in the file here:

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory,
  "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources", "ContextMenus.tr"}]
```

Examining the contents of that file, you can discover that the "Convert to Graphics" contextual menu item maps to the Mathematica command `` GraphComputation`GraphConvertToGraphics ``.  Thus, for example,

```
GraphComputation`GraphConvertToGraphics[
  Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}]] // Head

(* Out: Graphics *)
```

I actually prefer your `Show` technique, which is more natural and more likely to remain stable between versions, but it is nice to know how to find what commands these contextual menu items map to.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I imagine that `Show` probably calls `GraphConvertToGraphics` internally.