# Coordinate extraction and manipulating graphs as graphics objects

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Consider the image below:

```
GraphData[{"Wheel", 7}]
```

[image]

Is it possible in *Mathematica*  to lay several of these `Graph` along each other and then get the coordinates of the resultant network?

Something like these at the simplest case:

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Öskå I edited the question.

Comment: @Öskå I did not produce the second and third images in MMA. I just used paint in Windows and made those out of the first image.

Comment: There is one fundamental problem with this approach based on `GraphData`: the `VertexCoordinates` are only given as **approximate** real numbers, so that the coordinates that you can extract from the `Graphics` are not the exact geometric values. Basically, I think the information in `GraphData` is limited to the number of digits that can be visually discerned in a graph display, so you shouldn't use them for high-precision calculations. Not sure why they didn't implement exact values here...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the vertex coordinates, e.g.

```
g = GraphData[{"Wheel", 7}]
vc=PropertyValue[g, VertexCoordinates]
```

yielding:

```
{{-0.5, -0.866}, {0.5, -0.866}, {1., 0.}, {0.5, 0.866}, {-0.5, 
  0.866}, {-1., 0.}, {0., 0.}}
```

**UPDATE**

To do the other objects (without the overlaid lines):

```
grap = GraphicsComplex[vc, Line /@ List @@@ EdgeList[g]];
tr[p_] := GeometricTransformation[grap, TranslationTransform[p]]
```

First object:

```
gr1 = Graphics[{grap,
   tr[{1, 0}], tr[{-1/2, -Sin[Pi/3]}], tr[{-1/2, Sin[Pi/3]}]}]
```

[image]

Second object:

```
gr2 = Graphics[{grap, tr[{0, 2 Sin[Pi/3]}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**Update 3:** A one-liner

```
ClearAll[f];
f[g_, tr : {{_, _} ..}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
             Graphics[Translate[First@Show@g, {{0, 0}, ## & @@ tr}], opts]

g = GraphData[{"Wheel", 7}];
tr1 = {{1, 0}, {-1/2, -Sin[Pi/3]}, {-1/2, Sin[Pi/3]}};
tr2 = {{0, 2 Sin[Pi/3]}};
Row[f[g, #, ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {tr1, tr2}]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** The simplest approach to convert a `Graph` `g` to `Graphics` turns out to be `Show[g]` (see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25024/125) by becko -- thanks: @MarkMcClure). So, with `translations*` defined in previous update:

```
g = GraphData[{"Wheel", 7}];
g4 = First@Show[g];
g4a = Graphics[Translate[g4, #] & /@ translations1b, ImageSize -> 300];
g4b = Graphics[Translate[g4, #] & /@ translations2b, ImageSize -> 300];
Row[{g4a, g4b}]
(* same pictures as above *)
```

**Update:** slightly more streamlined version using `Translate` and GraphComputation`GraphConvertToGraphics:

```
g = GraphData[{"Wheel", 7}];
g2 = First@GraphComputation`GraphConvertToGraphics[g];
translations1 = {{1, 0}, {-1/2, -Sin[Pi/3]}, {-1/2, Sin[Pi/3]}};
translations2 = {{0, 2 Sin[Pi/3]}};
translations1b = Prepend[translations1, {{0, 0}}];
translations2b = Prepend[translations2, {{0, 0}}];


g3a = Graphics[Translate[g2, #] & /@ translations1b, ImageSize -> 300];
g3b = Graphics[Translate[g2, #] & /@ translations2b, ImageSize -> 300];
Row[{g3a, g3b}]
(* same pictures as above *)
```

---

**Original post:**

Borrowing the function `tr` from @ubdqn's excellent answer, and using the undocumented function GraphComputation`GraphConvertToGraphics:

```
tr2[g_, p_] := GeometricTransformation[g, TranslationTransform[p]];
g2 = First@GraphComputation`GraphConvertToGraphics[g];

g2a = Graphics[{g2, tr2[g2, #] & /@ translations1}, ImageSize -> 300];
g2b = Graphics[{g2, tr2[g2, #] & /@ translations2}, ImageSize -> 300];
Row[{g2a, g2b}]
(* same pictures as above *)
```

Comment: The GraphComputation`GraphConvertToGraphics function is called by `Show` when applied to a `Graph`.  Thus, `Show[g]` accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: @Mark, thank you!! Now that you mention I think I recently saw this cool trick somewhere on this site -- a post/comment by you most probably --, made a mental note to remember, and promptly forgot:) Will you post it as an answer, or should I update this answer?

Comment: Oh, it's just one tiny little change.  I thought about editing your answer but you can do it, if you want.  And, yes, I've posted the `GraphConvert` thing before but more recently learned of the more intuitive approach with `Show`.

Comment: @kguler +1 thanks for another useful tool and insight into Show for graphs.

Comment: @MarkMcClure thanks for commentary and insights...helpful for more complicated graphs.