# Label multiple edges between same vertices

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

I have a simple graph with multiple edges between two vertices, say:

```
Graph[{
  Labeled[a -> b, "A"],
  Labeled[a -> b, "B"]
}]
```

Unfortunately, Mathematica labels both edges "A".
[image: Graph with multiple edges to same vertices]

How can I label both distinct edges? They really both need to point to the same vertex.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Update 3:** Styling and labeling edges individually can now be more conveniently done using new-in-version-12.1 function [`EdgeTaggedGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeTaggedGraph.html):

```
labels = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
edges = {a -> b, a -> b, a -> b, a -> b, a -> e, e -> b};
styles = ColorData[97] /@ Range[6];

labelededges =  MapThread[Style[Labeled[#, #2], #3] &, {edges, labels, styles}] ;

EdgeTaggedGraph[labelededges, EdgeLabels -> "Name", 
 ImageSize -> Medium, EdgeLabelStyle -> 16]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** Dealing with the issue raised by @Kuba in the comments:

Using the function `LineScaledCoordinate` from the `GraphUtilities` package to place the text labels:

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]

labels ={"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};

Graph[{a -> b, a -> b, a -> b, a -> b, a -> e, e -> b},  
EdgeShapeFunction -> 
  ({Text[Last[labels = RotateLeft[labels]], LineScaledCoordinate[#, 0.5]], Arrow@#} &),
VertexLabels->"Name"]
```

[image]

**Update:** Using `EdgeShapeFunction`:

```
labels = Reverse @ {"A","B","C","D"};
i = 1;
Graph[{a -> b, a -> b, a -> b, a -> b},
 EdgeShapeFunction- > ({Text[labels[[i++]], Mean @ #],Arrow @ #}&)]
```

[image]

---

Simplest method to convert a `Graph` `g` to `Graphics` is to use `Show[g]` (see [this answer by @becko](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25024/125)).

We can post-process `Show[g]` to modify the `Text` primitives:

```
Show[Graph[{Labeled[a->b,"A"],Labeled[a->b,"B"]}]]/. 
   Text["A",{x_,y_/; (y<0.)},z___]:>Text["B",{x,y},z]
```

[image]

Or, we can construct a `Graph` with modified edge directions (and correct labels) and post-process it to change the edge directions:

```
Show[Graph[{Labeled[a->b,"A"], Labeled[b->a,"B"]}]]/. 
  BezierCurve[{{-1.,0.},m__,y_}]:>BezierCurve[{{1.,0.},m,{-1.,0.}}]
(* same picture *)
```

Comment: It may not be the best idea for more crowded places: `labels = Reverse@{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
i = 1;
Graph[{a -> b, a -> b, a -> b, a -> b, a -> e, e -> b}, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Text[labels[[i++]], Mean@#], Arrow@#} &)]`.

Comment: btw. for V9 something like `Graph[{a -> b, a -> b}]` yells that `Mixed graphs and multigraphs are not supported`. So in V10 it should work correctly with labeling, isn't it bug then?

Comment: @Kuba, regarding "isn`t it a bug` i agree. An re "crowded places", i can't think of a quick fix for now.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's a bit sad for me - as I'm constructing graphs with lots of vertices where the manual replacement might be a bit cumbersome. But thanks for the many ways you showed!

Comment: +1 This is a clever answer. My only problem is that now the `Graph` object is not self-contained: `i` must be reset before any extra call to the graph. Such a pity that internal edge functions use `ReplaceAll` so that one cannot identifiy different instances of the same edge...

Answer (score 9):

This ****, and so does my answer, but if it works it's not stupid, right? :)

```
p = Graph[{Labeled[a -> b, "A"], Labeled[a -> b, "B"]}];

grp = GraphComputation`GraphConvertToGraphics[p];

ReplacePart[grp, Position[grp, "A"][[1]] -> "B"]
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to try if this also works with Tooltip - as this is what I actually need with the number of edges I'm targeting.

Comment: @ThomasFankhauser it should but you have to locate and replace whole tooltip.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that in *Mathematica* 10.0.2 `Graph` does not natively support this by way of wrappers such as `Labeled`.  Note that each of these wrappers is converted to a canonical form that seems to support only one directive for each edge:

```
Table[
  InputForm @ Graph[{fn[a -> b, "A"], fn[a -> b, "B"]}],
  {fn, {Labeled, Annotation, Tooltip, Style, Hyperlink, EventHandler, Button}}
] // Column
```

> ```
> Graph[{a, b}, {DirectedEdge[a, b], DirectedEdge[a, b]},
>  {EdgeLabels -> {DirectedEdge[a, b] -> "A"}}]
>
> Graph[{a, b}, {DirectedEdge[a, b], DirectedEdge[a, b]},
>  {Properties -> {DirectedEdge[a, b] -> {Annotation -> "A"}}}]
>
> Graph[{a, b}, {DirectedEdge[a, b], DirectedEdge[a, b]},
>  {Properties -> {DirectedEdge[a, b] -> {Tooltip -> "A"}}}]
>
> Graph[{a, b}, {DirectedEdge[a, b], DirectedEdge[a, b]},
>  {EdgeStyle -> {DirectedEdge[a, b] -> {"A"}}}]
>
> Graph[{a, b}, {DirectedEdge[a, b], DirectedEdge[a, b]},
>  {Properties -> {DirectedEdge[a, b] -> {Hyperlink -> "A"}}}]
>
> Graph[{a, b}, {DirectedEdge[a, b], DirectedEdge[a, b]},
>  {Properties -> {DirectedEdge[a, b] -> {EventHandler -> "A"}}}]
>
> Graph[{a, b}, {DirectedEdge[a, b], DirectedEdge[a, b]},
>  {Properties -> {DirectedEdge[a, b] -> {Button -> Unevaluated["B"]}}}]
> ```

Comment: The problem is not only in wrappers. `Graph[{a -> b, a -> b}, EdgeWeight -> {1, 2}, 
 EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]` is displayed incorrectly despite the correct `InputForm`.

Answer (score 4):

If your application allows it, one workaround to Mathematica's inability to handle multigraphs in Graph objects is simply to allow edge labels to be lists of multiple labels.  So, for example, the original graph could be represented via either of these forms:

```
Graph[{Labeled[a -> b, {"A", "B"}]}]

Graph[{Labeled[DirectedEdge[a, b], {"A", "B"}]}]
```

In representing finite state machines, this has served me quite well.  In addition, I don’t use the Graph object to store the information about my machines, since Mathematica likes to “own” the data contained in those objects.  So my approach is to create a separate FiniteStateMachine data structure in which I can define my own rules (and yes: multigraphs are supported there).  I only need to produce Graph objects 'on the fly' when I need to see what a FiniteStateMachine looks like.  This also lets me skirt around the differences in how Graph objects are handled in MMA 9, 10 and 11, all of which I want my code to support.

I also experimented with GraphPlot, since it *does* support multigraphs.  However, it only works with Rule-based edges.  If you use DirectedEdge to define the edges, it won’t work.  Furthermore, the results are far less graphically appealing.  So, for example, the original multigraph could be represented this way using GraphPlot:

```
GraphPlot[
    {{a -> b, "A"}, {a -> b, "B"}},
    DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabeling -> True
]
```

Answer (score 3):

The new 12.1 `EdgeTaggedGraph` feels like a mess to be honest. The tags are not labels, so they don't visualize in the graph. In the example above you've hacked `Labeled` to do the labeling instead. The problem with that is that it seems to be incompatible with our ability to append or modify graphs. For instance, if one wanted to add a new edge with a new label with `EdgeAdd`, one can not use `Labeled`. The other way of showing labels, `EdgeLabel`, isn't compatible with `EdgeTaggedGraph`.

```
EdgeTaggedGraph[{A -> B, A -> B, A -> B}, 
  EdgeLabels -> {(A -> B) -> 1, (A -> B) -> 2, (A -> B) -> 3}]
```

What is even more crazy is, if you look in the documentation for  `EdgeTaggedGraph`, they use `EdgeLabels` in a 100 examples for `EdgeTaggedGraph` that are useless because the graphs have no duplicated edges.  It looks ass if someone just copied examples from the documentation of `Graph`.

Comment: I, too, think the documentation examples were just copied from `Graph`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the third argument of `DirectedEdge`, together with `EdgeLabels -> "EdgeTag"`:

```
Graph[
  {DirectedEdge[a, b, "A"], DirectedEdge[a, b, "B"]}, 
  EdgeLabels -> "EdgeTag"
]
```

[image: Graph]