# Animate point going around a triangle

Tags: graphics, animation

How can I animate a point moving on a triangle's sides?
I can generate a triangle and point, but I have no idea how to define point movement.
I'm guessing that I have to use $\sin$ and $\cos$ in coordinates, but I can't find a way to define the triangle in this way.
Can someone help me a bit with that?

[image: point on triangle]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you interpret your geometric shape as a NURBS of degree 1 (linear), you can proceed with the following, extremely simple code:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0.5, 1.5}}; (* just an example *)
s = BSplineFunction[pts, SplineClosed -> True, SplineDegree -> 1];
Animate[ParametricPlot[s[t], {t, 0, 1}, Epilog :> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[s[t]]}], {t, 0., 1.}]
```

This yields the triangular (outer) graph of the following display:

[image: Same BSplineFunction, but increased degree and custom weights]

Just replace `Animate` by `Manipulate` to give the user control over the point.

**Note** This is a rather general approach applicable in wide areas, since you can vary your control points as well as the spline degree, but the `BSplineFunction` will always yield the curve between arguments 0 and 1. In essence, you can display quite every geometric shape using this approach. For more complex ones, some adjustment to B-spline weights will be necessary, though.

The inner of those curves result from *the same control points as before*, but degree 2 and weights explicitly given as `SplineWeights -> {.1, 1, 1}`. Just exchange the `s`-line above with this one:

```
s = BSplineFunction[pts, SplineClosed -> True, SplineDegree -> 2, SplineWeights -> {.1, 1, 1}];
```

I hope this might be of some help to you.

Comment: Simon, would you consider using a variation of your user name?  We have a [member of three years](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/34/simon) using the same name, and though he isn't as active recently it still confuses me when I see you post or comment.  (This is merely a suggestion; you are not required to take action.)

Comment: Simon might be a rather common user name, I take it.

Problem is: I had some problems with my Stackexchange account already, up to the point of having had to contact support for help... I will see what I can do, however, without messing up my account once again.

Did I mention, how inexplicably unintuitive the Stackexchange account management is? ;)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I tried, but Stackexchange won't let me: I will have to wait until some time in February. Maybe you will have become acquainted to my user name until then. Either way: I can't change anything for the moment. :|

Comment: I second @Mr.Wizard because your contributions to the site are very well received. It wouldn't matter if you were the standard "novice new user type", but you aren't. And it's a lame to have that kind of confusion among two good site citizens. Please don't forget to _try_ changing you user name once the site allows you.

Comment: Simon, as a community elected moderator I believe I am able to change your user name.  If you tell me what you would like I shall attempt it.

Comment: Ah. Good to hear that. Please change the username to `Jinxed`. Thank you!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Please see my previous comment. I forgot to mention you explicitly.

Comment: @Jinxed Complete.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

### Using `RegionNearest`

This approach should work regardless of whether the triangle is filled or not.  Here, we will represent the triangle unfilled, i.e. as a one-dimensional region, `r1`, a line, embedded in  a plane.

```
r1 = Line[{{0, 0}, {3, 1}, {2, 0}, {0, 0}}];
RegionDimension[r1]
RegionEmbeddingDimension[r1]
```

> 1
>   2

Get the radius of a circle, with the triangle centroid as center, that intersects the farthest vertex of the triangle.

```
c = RegionCentroid[r1];  (* the gray point *)
radius = Max[EuclideanDistance[c, #] & /@ {{0, 0}, {3, 1}, {2, 0}}];
```

Animate a black point going around the circle.

And display a (red) point on the triangle that is currently nearest to the black point on the circle.

```
Animator[Dynamic[n], {0, N[2 Pi], .01}]
Graphics[{r1, AbsolutePointSize[10],
  Gray, Point[c],
  Black, Dynamic@ Point[d = radius {Cos[n], Sin[n]} + c],
  {Red, Dynamic@Point[RegionNearest[r1, d]]},
  {Dashed, Circle[c, radius]}}]
```

[image: animation2]

Comment: Unusual in both method and result. +1

Answer (score 13):

[Thanks to kguler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72011/5478), I now know there is something like: `LineScaledCoordinate`.

```
vertices = Table[{Cos[i], Sin[i]}, {i, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/3.}];
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]

Slider[Dynamic@t]
Graphics[{

  EdgeForm @ Thick, FaceForm @ None, Polygon @ vertices
  ,
  AbsolutePointSize @ 12, Red, Dynamic[Point[LineScaledCoordinate[vertices, t]]]
  }
 ]
```

> [image]

---

Just in case you can't load `` GraphUtilities` ``, use `Interpolation`:

```
f = Interpolation[Table[{{i}, vertices[[i]]}, {i, Length@vertices}], 
                  InterpolationOrder -> 1]

Slider[Dynamic @ t, {1, 4}]
Graphics[{
        EdgeForm@Thick, FaceForm@None, Polygon@vertices
        , 
        AbsolutePointSize@12, Red, Dynamic[Point[f[t]]]
        }]
```

This method is different because each edge has parametric length of 1. If you want uniform "velocity" then you have to take care of `{i}` in `Table`.

Answer (score 11):

```
e = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {5.5, 1.5}, {0, 0}}; (*triangle vertices*)

(*point position as a function of time*)
p[t_, e_] := Piecewise[{
    {(1 - t)*e[[1]] + t*e[[2]], 0 <= t <= 1},
    {(1 - (t - 1))*e[[2]] + (t - 1)*e[[3]], 1 < t <= 2},
    {(1 - (t - 2))*e[[3]] + (t - 2)*e[[1]], 2 < t <= 3}
    }];

(*animation*)
Animate[
 Show[
  Graphics[Line[e]],
  Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[p[t, e]]}]
  ]
 , {t, 0, 3}
 ]
```

EDIT (Make the point move at constant speed)

Length of triangle edges:

```
d = EuclideanDistance[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ Partition[e, 2, 1]
```

Modified `p` function so that the point moves at a normalized speed of `d[[1]]` (i.e., move along the first edge in time equal to $1$)

```
pver2[t_, e_] := Piecewise[{
    {(1 - t)*e[[1]] + t*e[[2]], 0 <= t <= 1},

    {(1 - (t - 1)/(d[[2]]/d[[1]]))*e[[2]] + (t - 1)*
       e[[3]]/(d[[2]]/d[[1]]), 1 < t <= 1 + d[[2]]/d[[1]]},

    {(1 - (t - (1 + d[[2]]/d[[1]]))/(d[[3]]/d[[1]]))*
       e[[3]] + (t - (1 + d[[2]]/d[[1]]))*e[[1]]/(d[[3]]/d[[1]]), 
     1 + d[[2]]/d[[1]] < t <= 1 + d[[2]]/d[[1]] + d[[3]]/d[[1]]}}];
```

Animation:

```
Animate[Show[Graphics[Line[e]], 
  Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[pver2[t, e]]}]], {t, 0, 
  1 + d[[2]]/d[[1]] + d[[3]]/d[[1]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Should `e` be modified to `{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0.5, 1.5}, {0, 0}}` to close the triangle?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Indeed, thanks for noticing

Comment: Very simple and clean solution. Is't there a way to make a point move in same speed on all sides? I know that I can adjust t param to slow it down or make it move faster, but it will still change speed on sides.

Comment: @Dcortez Please see edited answer for an (probably not elegant) implementation of the constant speed animation

Comment: Maybe not cleanest but working. Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my modest attempt, based on a formula given in [this math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/41954), with a few affine transformations thrown in:

```
triangle[pts_?MatrixQ, t_] :=
         AffineTransform[{Transpose[{{2, -1, -1}/3, {0, 1, -1}/Sqrt[3]}.pts], Mean[pts]}][
               Sec[t - π (2 Floor[3 t/(2 π)] + 1)/3] {Cos[t], Sin[t]}/2]

pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 3}/2};
mt[t_] = triangle[pts, t];
tpic = ParametricPlot[mt[t], {t, 0, 2 π}, Frame -> True];

Animate[Show[tpic, 
             Epilog -> {{Directive[ColorData[1, 1], AbsolutePointSize[4]], Point[pts]},
                        {Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[8]], Point[mt[u]]}}],
        {u, 0, 2 π, π/12}]
```

[image: point going around a triangle]

Answer (score 4):

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   Line[p[[{1, 2, 3, 1}]]],
   PointSize@Large, Red,
   Point[With[{f = Floor[i], t = FractionalPart[i]}, {1 - t, t}.p[[Mod[{f, f + 1}, 3, 1]]]]]
   }],
 {{p, {{0, 0}, {0.8, 0.9}, {0.5, 1.5}}}, Locator}, {i, 1, 4}]
```

[image]

It's also easy to generalize to polygons.

Answer (score 4):

```
SeedRandom[77]
coords = Append[#, First@#] &@RandomReal[1, {3, 2}];
```

#### **[`Arrowheads`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrowheads.html) + [`Clock`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clock.html)**

```
Dynamic[Graphics[{Arrowheads[{{.05, Clock[{0, 1}, 5, 3]}}], 
   Blue, Arrow @ coords}, Axes -> False]]
```

[image]

With a custom arrowhead:

```
pnt = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0}]}]; 

Dynamic[Graphics[{Arrowheads[{{.05, Clock[{0, 1}, 5, 3], pnt}}], 
   Blue, Arrow @ coords}, Axes -> False]]
```

[image]

Multiple points moving at different speeds on the boundary of an arbitrary polygon and stopping after three tours:

```
SeedRandom[77]
coords = Append[#, First@#] &@RandomReal[1, {10, 2}];
pnts = Table[Graphics[{ColorData[63, "ColorList"][[i]], AbsolutePointSize[15], 
     Point[{0, 0}]}], {i, 5}];

Dynamic[Graphics[{Blue, 
   Arrowheads[Table[{.05, Mod[i/5 + Clock[{0, 1}, i, 3], 1], pnts[[i]]}, {i, 1, 
      5}]], 
   Arrow @ coords}, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {{-.1, 1.1}, {-.1, 1.1}}]]
```

[image]

#### **[`Arrowheads`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrowheads.html) + [`Animate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animate.html)**

```
Animate[Graphics[{Arrowheads[{{.05, t, pnt}}], Blue, Arrow @ coords}, 
  Axes -> False], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]