# LineScaledCoordinate problem for exact coordinates

Tags: graphics, functions, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.4 or earlier and persisting through 11.2**

`CASE:2326540`

Solution: Wait and use `N` meanwhile.

---

I've faced this problem writing an answer for [Animate point go round a triangle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72415/5478).

For coordinates with exact values, instead of moving along a multi-line `LineScaledCoordinate` is mooving along extrapolated first segment.

It is not always the case but always for exact values. `N` is the fix.

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]

vertices = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}};

Slider[Dynamic@t]

Graphics[{
  
  EdgeForm@Thick, FaceForm@None, Polygon@vertices
  ,
  AbsolutePointSize@12, Red, Dynamic[Point[LineScaledCoordinate[vertices, t]]]
  ,
  AbsolutePointSize@12, Blue, Dynamic[Point[LineScaledCoordinate[N@vertices, t]]]
  },
  PlotRange -> {{0, 4.5}, {0, 4.5}}, Frame -> True
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally `LineScaledCoordinate` use

```
Position[d, _?(#1 >= t &)]
```

to detect a current segment. Here `d` is an accumulated list of distances (relative to the total length of segments). However, algebraic expressions are not atomic:

```
t = 0.5;
d = {0, 1/(3 + Sqrt[2]), 3/(3 + Sqrt[2]), 1};
Position[d, _?(#1 >= t &)]
Position[N@d, _?(#1 >= t &)]
(* {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 
  1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 1, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {3, 2, 
  1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}, {3}, {4}} *)
(* {{3}, {4}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. So you agree it is a bug, right?

Comment: @Kuba Yes! The level specification in `Position` was missed.