# Adding vertical dotted lines to a plot with different markers as dots

Tags: plotting

Based on [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3561/how-to-add-a-vertical-line-to-a-plot) I am able to draw dotted or dashed vertical lines in a plot using `Epilog`. For example (from the answer I linked)

```
f[x_] := (x^2 z)/((x^2 - y^2)^2 + 4 q^2 x^2) /. {y -> π/15, z -> 1, q -> π/600}
Quiet[maxy = FindMaxValue[f[x], x]*1.1]
lineStyle = {Thick, Red, Dashed};
line1 = Line[{{π/15 + 1/50, 0}, {π/15 + 1/50, maxy}}];
line2 = Line[{{π/15 - 1/50, 0}, {π/15 - 1/50, maxy}}];
Plot[{f[x]}, {x, π/15 - 1/20, π/15 + 1/20}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic}, 
  Epilog -> {Directive[lineStyle], line1, line2}]
```

Leads to

[image]

Now, what I'd like to do is not plot dashed lines, but plot lines that are essentially dotted with a certain marker, such as a `Disk` or a `Rectangle`, or even a `Polygon`. Is there a way to do this? I've looked into `Dashing`, but I don't really see any marker options there.

A rough mockup would be something like this
[image]
While I don't disagree with the comments that there might be better solutions in terms of how one represents data properly, it would still be nice to be able to try.

Comment: @Kuba I don't really see how that would work. Make 20+ little arrows (with different heads) and put them at small increments from each other vertically?

Comment: `Graphics[{Arrowheads[{.1, #, Graphics[{Black, Circle[]}]} & /@ 
    Range[0, 1, .1]], White, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {2, 1}}]}]` more or less, just a tip. You can also use [LineScaledCoordinate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72427/5478) to generate positions along lines and put whatever you need there with `Inset`.

Comment: I see, I'll give that some thought!

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? It violates the canons of good visual design. Surely the data is more important than the two vertical lines, so you should not draw more attention to the lines than to the data itself.

Comment: Good point! I'm trying to think of how to explain it without getting into the specifics. I have a set of curves (say 6) in frequency space (x-axis); they are the main objects of interest, indeed. They have a legend and are color coded. But they occur because we excite some atom with a laser at certain frequencies, and these exact frequencies I want to indicate with vertical gray dashed lines. Each laser has a different name however, so I would like to link the names of each laser to the symbol used for the 'dash-marker' of that gray line.

Comment: That is as an alternative to putting the name next to the line in the plot, which also works but distracts, like you said, from the more important data. So I figured a light gray line with a certain symbol would be rather inconspicuous, and then I can define what they stand for in the figure caption. I could make a sketch if that helps; perhaps one would have a better suggestion

Comment: @user, a mockup would certainly be nice, please post it if you can.

Comment: p.s. `GridLines` are faster than `FindMaxValue`. Take a look at [118419](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118419/5478)

Comment: @Kuba that might be true; I just figured that doing something like this might be easier with `Epilog` than with `GridLines`.

Comment: Please reconsider it then :) `Plot[{f[x]}, {x, \[Pi]/15 - 1/20, \[Pi]/15 + 1/20}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic}, GridLines -> {Pi/15 + (1/50 {1, -1})}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red, Dashed]]`

Comment: @Kuba You misunderstand (or I was unclear); I meant that epilog might be better suited for doing it with custom markers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it would be to have a second `ListPlot` in the background, and you can use the `PlotMarkers` option.

```
f[x_] := (x^2 z)/((x^2 - y^2)^2 + 4 q^2 x^2) /. {y -> \[Pi]/15, 
   z -> 1, q -> \[Pi]/600}
Quiet[maxy = FindMaxValue[f[x], x]*1.1];

plotmarkers = Graphics`PlotMarkers[]
line1 = {1/50 + \[Pi]/15, #} & /@ Subdivide[0, maxy, 20];
line2 = {-(1/50) + \[Pi]/15, #} & /@ Subdivide[0, maxy, 20];
Show[
 Plot[{f[x]}, {x, \[Pi]/15 - 1/20, \[Pi]/15 + 1/20}, 
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotLegends -> {"plot"}],
 ListPlot[{line1, line2}, PlotMarkers -> plotmarkers[[{3, 5}]],
  PlotLegends -> {"line 1", "line 2"}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]