# Differently colored edges of same direction in a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, output-formatting, style

When I try to color edges in a graph that point to different vertices, it works properly:

```
Graph[{Style[DirectedEdge[1, 2], Red], Style[DirectedEdge[2, 3], Blue]}]
```

> [image]

However, if I try to give different colors to two edges that involve the same vertices, it does not seem to work properly:

```
Graph[{Style[DirectedEdge[1, 2], Red], Style[DirectedEdge[1, 2], Blue]}]
```

> [image]

We see that only one of the colors is registered.
How should I apply the coloring properly in this case?

Comment: Related Q/A:  [Label multiple edges between same vertices](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72003/125)

Comment: Do you mean: `Graph[{Style[DirectedEdge[1, 2], Red], 
  Style[DirectedEdge[2, 1], Blue]}]`?

Comment: @bills No, both edges intentiionally should have the same direction.

Comment: See also comments here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92014/12 There's a fundamental problem with multigraphs and properties ...

Comment: @kglr based on the info in that link, I am drawn towards giving up on trying to color my graphs...

Comment: @Kagaratsch,  or wait till version 12:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** With new-in-version-12.1 function[`EdgeTaggedGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeTaggedGraph.html) we can style and label edges individually:

```
stylededges = Style @@@ Thread[{ a->b, {Red, Blue, Green, Orange}}];

EdgeTaggedGraph[stylededges, EdgeLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

Modifying the answer in [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72003/125):

```
styles={Red, Blue, Green, Orange};
i=1;
Graph[{a->b,a->b,a->b, a->b}, EdgeShapeFunction->({styles[[i++]],Arrow@#}&)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:** dealing with more general cases

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]

styles1 = {Red, Blue, Green, Orange};
styles2 = { Purple, Cyan, Pink};
labels1 = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
labels2 = { "E", "F", "G"};

Module[{i=1,j=1,i2,j2}, Graph[{a->b,a->b,a->b, a->b, a->c,c->a,b->c,b->c,b->c, b->a}, 
 EdgeShapeFunction->{(a->b)->({styles1[[i2 = i++]], Text[labels1[[i2]],
    LineScaledCoordinate[#, 0.5]], Arrow@#}&),
  (b->c)->({styles2[[j2 = j++]], Text[labels2[[j2]],
    LineScaledCoordinate[#, 0.5]], Arrow@#}&)}, VertexLabels->"Name"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Module[{i = 1, j = 1, i2, j2}, 
 Graph[Join[(Property[#, EdgeShapeFunction -> ({styles1[[i2 = i++]], 
          Text[labels1[[i2]], LineScaledCoordinate[#, 0.5]], 
          Arrow@#} &)] & /@ {a -> b, a -> b, a -> b}), 
   (Property[#, EdgeShapeFunction -> ({styles2[[j2 = j++]], 
          Text[labels2[[j2]], LineScaledCoordinate[#, 0.5]], 
          Arrow@#} &)] & /@ {e -> b, e -> b, e -> b}), {a -> e, e -> c, c -> e, a -> c}], 
  VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  EdgeStyle -> {(a -> c) -> Dashed, (a -> b) -> DotDashed , 
         (e -> c) -> Directive[Dotted, Green]}, 
  ImageSize -> 500] ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the general question of how to specify colors that are not in an assigned order throughout a general multigraph.

Comment: @David, i updated with two examples of how this hack could be used in a more complicated setting.