# Having parallel edges with different colors between edges in a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am using Mathematica 11.0.0

I have a graph with multiple directed edges between two vertices.  Is there a way to color these edges with different colors in Mathematica 11?

I have seen  some suggestions in other questions here but they all refer to older versions of Mathematica.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Differently colored edges of same direction in a graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132624/125) and closely related: [Label multiple edges between same vertices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72003/125)

Comment: No change in 11.x, and see here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92014/12