# How can I re-create the original Graph object from Graphics object into which that Graph was converted previously?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, conversion

We can convert a `Graph` into `Graphics` very easily like it is shown in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25024/21532). My question is: how to convert a `Graphics` object into the original `Graph` from which it was created? Like the `g1`,`g2` and `g3` in the following:

```
SeedRandom[1]
g1 = Show[RandomGraph[{6, 10}]]
Head[g1]
```

> [image]
>
> ```
> Graphics
> ```

```
g2 = GraphPlot3D[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 
   2 -> 5, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 5, 4 -> 5}]
```

> [image]

```
g3 = GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 
   4 -> 4}, VertexLabeling -> True, DirectedEdges -> True]
```

> [image]

Comment: Interesting!Why I get so many close in such a valuable post?

Comment: Your question as given can't be answered for the obvious reasons. You should probably ask something like: "How can I re-create the original `Graph` object from `Graphics` object into which that `Graph` was converted previously?" It would be a well-defined question.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Actually I can't distinguish the difference between both.But I have changed it as what you suggest.I hope it will be more better post. :)

Comment: I have edited your question in order to make it simpler and more clear.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks very very much.

Comment: I think this question is well reasonable and I already voted do not close it and upvoted it. The ability to convert easily from one representation to another always was (and is) the most strong advantage of *Mathematica*.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I'm blushing for this every time. :)

Comment: Shall we preserve the points' location or simply preserving the graph's topological structure will be enough?

Comment: @Wjx Position,vertices's ordering and direct or undirect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WOW! I made it!

Code first~

```
Graphics2Graph[g_] := 
 Module[{cd = 
    If[FreeQ[g, Line], 
     DirectedEdge @@@ (Extract[g, Position[g, Arrow[___]]] /. 
        Arrow[x_, ___] :> {First@x, Last@x}), 
     UndirectedEdge @@@ Extract[g, Position[g, Line[_]]][[1, 1]]]},
  Graph[cd, 
   VertexCoordinates -> 
    Extract[Extract[g, Position[g, GraphicsComplex[___]]][[1, 1]], 
     List /@ VertexList@Graph[cd]], VertexLabels -> "Name"]]

Graphics2Graph /@ {g1, g2, g3}
```

Well, the method of doing this is quite simple.
After analyzed several Graph's `FullForm`, I realized that all the Graphics created are in the form of `GraphicsComplex` and all the useful information are stored in the form of either a great `Line` or several `Arrow`. The storage, fortunately, are in regular forms:

```
(*Line Form*)
Line[{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 5}}]

(*Arrow Form*)
Arrow[{2,1}]
Arrow[{2,3,4,5,1}]
Arrow[{1,2},0.2]
```

Also, I found out that in one graph, only one form will be presented. So either a graph is totally presented by Line Form or totally presented by Arrow Form.

So the only thing I'll have to do is to find out all the `Line` Expression or `Arrow` Expression and properly convert them into styled forms. The code simply do this job with `Position` and `Extract`.

Seemingly this version do is wide-range supportive~ I've tried a few examples in Graph's documentation and it seems that this function works fine. Also the speed is quite high too~

Comment: Nice job and I found `InputForm[DiscretizeGraphics[g2]]` will get a very simple form.But we cann't macth it by `Cases`

Comment: Try my method of Position and Extract

Comment: I mean to process Graphics3D

Comment: oh, alright. :)

Comment: And `SeedRandom[1]
g1 = Show[Graph[RandomGraph[{6, 10}], VertexLabels -> "Name"]]
Graphics2Graph[g1]` seem to give some unexpected result?`SeedRandom[1]
g1 = Show[RandomGraph[{6, 10}]]
Graphics2Graph[g1]` will mix the direct or undirect? :)

Comment: It seem that in this case, the graphics is generated using not `GraphicsComplex` but simple `Graphics` instead. Maybe in this case we can still transform it into a graph using some modification but there'll be no clear statement of which point is 1 and which is 2. So personally I will consider this form of graphics cannot be transformed back to Graph form if you want to preserve the vertexes' name. Try `RandomGraph[{600,1000}]` and you'll see that in this situation, even using your eyes, you can not know which point is 1 and which is 2 as they all mixed together.

Comment: Make it simple and clear, Using Show will **compress** the data into a pure `Graphics` form, so it will be impossible to convert it back in general.

Comment: Thanks for your vivid explaination.And I'll be at your side.

Answer (score 0):

I made it with a non-perferct solution,but actually I don't content with it.I hope to get a general methond to do this rather than customized for every `Graphics`.

## For g1

```
pos = Cases[Normal[g1], _Arrow, Infinity][[All, 1]];
rule = MapIndexed[Rule[#, First[#2]] &, 
   DeleteDuplicates@Catenate[pos]];
Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ (pos /. rule), 
 VertexCoordinates -> Reverse /@ rule, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

The ordering of the vertices seem to been refined

## For g2

```
data = Cases[g2, _GraphicsComplex, Infinity];
Graph3D[UndirectedEdge @@@ data[[1, 2, 1, 2, 1]], 
 VertexCoordinates -> data[[1, 1]], GraphStyle -> "SmallNetwork"]
```

[image]

## For g3

```
pos = Through[{First, Last}[#]] & /@ 
   Cases[Normal[g3], _Arrow, Infinity][[All, 1]];
rule = MapIndexed[Rule[#, First[#2]] &, 
   DeleteDuplicates@Catenate[pos]];
Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ pos /. rule, 
 VertexCoordinates -> Reverse /@ rule, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]